# Python Tkinter filedialog save and open issues (not opening, not letting choose name to save)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a couple of issues with opening and saving files using tkinters file dialog. Here is a small reproduced code of the issue I am having.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def open_file():
    tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='.', title='Select File', filetypes=(('Excel files', ('*.xl*', '*.xlsx', '*.xlsm', '*.xlsb', '.xlam', '*.xltx', '*.xltm', '*.xls', '*.xla', '*.xlt', '*.xlm', '*.xlw')), ('Text Files', ('*.txt', '*.csv')), ('all files', '*.*')))


def save_file():
    tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir='.', title='Save File', filetypes=(('Excel files', ('*.xl*', '*.xlsx', '*.xlsm', '*.xlsb', '.xlam', '*.xltx', '*.xltm', '*.xls', '*.xla', '*.xlt', '*.xlm', '*.xlw')), ('Text Files', ('*.txt', '*.csv')), ('all files', '*.*')))
    wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
    wb.save('new_name' + '.xlsx')


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        open_btn = tk.Button(master, text='Open', command=open_file)
        save_btn = tk.Button(master, text='Save', command=save_file)

        open_btn.pack()
        save_btn.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

This code works, but not the way I want it to. When I click the open button the filedialog window pops up, but I can't actually open any files. If I click a file then click open the filedialog window immediately closes. The same thing happens if I just double-click a file. However, I can right-click a file and select open and that works. How can I get the first two methods to allow me to open a file?

As for the save function, it works, but also not like I'd like it to work. The file dialog opens, but the user can't name the file themselves. They can type something in and click save, but it won't' actually name the file with that name. Instead, it names the new file 'new_name' since that's what is in my function. I was under the impression that it would default to 'new_name' in the filedialog window, then allow the user to edit the name if he/she wishes. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: `askopenfilename()` and `asksaveasfilename()` *return* the selected filename.  It's entirely up to you to do something with the returned value, it's not going to magically change the meaning of the following code.

Comment: Hmm, I feel like I'm still confused. Sorry. I was under the impression that these would allow you to open a new file and save a new file? Just like doing it in in a regular word/excel document? So it's "asking" the user to open a file. I'd like the user to be able to save a file with a name of their choosing.

Comment: Do you not understand how to call a function and use its return value?  Calling these particular functions, and then throwing away their return value, makes them utterly pointless.

Comment: I thought I did, but I guess I don't know because I'm still confused. I didn't think you needed to return a value for these specific functions. They are just used to open the file dialog box, or so I thought. I don't understand what exactly I need to return for this specific function when I just wanted it to open a dialog box then let the user make adjustments from there.

Comment: Yes, they open the file dialog box - and return the filename that the user chose (or `None` if the user cancelled the dialog).  The dialogs don't actually do anything with the chosen file, how would they know what you wanted them to do?  Assign the return value to a variable, use that variable where you're currently hard-coding a filename.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get it figured out using your suggestions. I saved the return value as a variable and used os.startfile(var) for the open function, then used the var as the filename to save it for that function. I appreciate it!